# Check every input class where his value lenght is 0 and change property display to none

Tags: jquery

I want to check every input class inside a table and set the property of tr parent to none if the input have a length of 0.

I tried with this code, but didn't worked:

```
$('.ewd-otp-input').each(function() {
if( $(this).val().length === 0 ) {
    $(this).closest("tr").css("display", "none");
}
});
```

HTML Structure:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="dni">DNI:</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input name="dni" id="ewd-otp-input-1" class="ewd-otp-text-input" type="text" value="6876">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="nombre-empresa">Nombre de la empresa:</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input name="nombre-empresa" id="ewd-otp-input-2" class="ewd-otp-text-input" type="text" value="pokpo">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="cifnif">CIF/NIF:</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input name="cifnif" id="ewd-otp-input-3" class="ewd-otp-text-input" type="text" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="cv">CV:</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input name="cv" class="ewd-otp-file-input" type="file" value="https://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/16_RF_Planta-de-distribución-Sup-exposicion_A3.pdf">
            <br>Current File: <a href="https://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/16_RF_Planta-de-distribución-Sup-exposicion_A3.pdf" target="blank">Ver archivo</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Well there are no elements with class `ewd-otp-input` in your HTML

Comment: yes. look this:             <input name="cifnif" id="ewd-otp-input-3" class="ewd-otp-text-input" type="text" value="">

Comment: Look closely i.e. `'ewd-otp-text-input' !== 'ewd-otp-input'`

Comment: `class="ewd-otp-text-input"` will not match `$('.ewd-otp-input')`, when changing your selector your code works: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/z7q63k81/)